# How to use a C macro / inline function to with a variable function name?

Tags: c, oop, macros, inline-functions

Essentially, I'm simulating object-oriented programming in basic C, due to necessity. For my own convenience, I'd like to use a macro or an inline function to reduce the amount of code I need to write. For my 400+ variables, each needs a structure like

```
int x;
int get_x(){
    return x;
}
void set_x(int a){
    x = a;
}
```

I was hoping there was some intelligent way to write this as a macro oneliner, so that I can feed type `foo(x)` and it'll replace it with all that code. The difficulty, I think, is in using the variable `x`
 as a string, so that it can be used in function titles.

Is there some C guru out there who's come across this sort of thing before?

Comment: I think you need to explain some more about your motivation, because to me using `x` to represent the value seems more intuitive than `get_x()` for the simple case you present above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define MAKE_OOP_VAR(var_type, var_name) \
var_type var_name; \
var_type get_##var_name() { return var_name; } \
void set_##var_name(var_type tmp) { var_name = tmp; } \

MAKE_OOP_VAR(int, x);
```

Not compile tested but off the top of my head.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect, works like a charm. Thanks a million. What is the function of the `##`?

Comment: @James Concatenation in macros, so that it concatenates the name of the variable to the function name instead of naming it get_var_name it will expand it to be get_x instead